# Player do youtube não funciona no iOS

Tags: javascript, html5, ios, youtube, youtube-api

Galera to com um problema aqui com videos do youtube, tenho ele como opção de player de musica no site no canto inferior direito, ele funciona normal exceto nos dispositivos moveis iOS, o que ocorre é que não consigo dar play na musica.

Segue um dos sites que contem o player. 
[site](https://noivos.casar.com/felipe-e-caroline#/pagina/layouts)

```
player = new YT.Player(attrs.container, { 
    height: '200', 
    width: '200', 
    videoId: getIdFromUrl(videoUrl), 
    playerVars: { 
        html5: 1,
        enablejsapi: 1, 
        playsinline: 1 
        //origin: extraService.site_root_url.replace('http:', 'https:') 
        //origin: extraService.site_root_url 
    }, 
    events: { 
        'onReady': onPlayerReady, 
        'onStateChange': onStateChange 
    } 
});
```

esse é o iframe que ele me gera:

```
<iframe id="sdn-player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2RtzSLLngc8?enablejsapi=1&amp;playsinline=1&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fnoivos.casar.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: Você usa alguma função para dar **play** ?

Comment: Coloca no seu CSS, a propriedade `cursor:pointer:` no botão de Play.

Comment: ja tem esse css no botão

Comment: Desculpa, não quis te ofender. Coloca essa variável `html5: 1,` dentro do `playerVars`. E coloque no seu POST as funções `OnPlayerReady` e `OnStateChange`.

Comment: @Diego-Souza não entendi a parte do POST

Comment: POST é isso que você postou aqui no site. Edite sua pergunta e coloque as funções que eu disse para podermos ver o que elas executam

Comment: Mas as funções OnplayerReady e OnStateChange ja tem, esta no final no events

Comment: Você não colocou a vírgula depois do `html5: 1`.

Comment: pronto ja coloquei a virgula

Comment: O problema esta aonde o @Diego Souza falou, esta faltando uma vírgula no `html5: 1`, acaba gerando um erro de javascript. 
As funções `onPlayerReady` e `onStateChange` são apenas callbacks

Comment: Mesmo com o html5: 1, não funcionou, o player ainda não roda no iOS e só esse player que não roda, pois colocando um video normal na pagina ele roda.